# How to show distance on JOSM

Tags: openstreetmap

On the JOSM interface I have the background colour as white. The scale bar top left shows distance using white text. This is invisible on a white background. Can the colour of the scale bar text be changed so that is is visible when the background is white? JOSM version 17013 Java 1.8.0_271.